# Dynamically populate php array using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How can I implement the code:

```
$numberList3 = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
 $numberList3[$i] = $i;
}
print_r($numberList3);
```

Using a foreach loop as the no. of times the loop is going to execute is decided by the user at run time.
Any suggestion.?

Comment: Why `foreach`? Why not `for` with a variable in place of `10`?

Comment: BTW: `range(0, 9)` – less typing.

Comment: Seriously, there can be many answer to this, be little more specific. why are you trying such a thing ? People here might be able to give you better suggestion than `foreach`.

Comment: More Specific.? I want to populate $numberList3 array dynamically the value it will hold will be value from a textbox.

Comment: `$numberList3 = range(0, $_POST['textbox'])`, or: `for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['textbox']; $i++) ..`... So many possibilities. You don't need `foreach` at all. You just need to understand variables; and that's really basic.

Comment: Textbox id, name can be product_1, product_2. however the value can be  30, 589, 5879 or any random no.

Comment: You'll have to come up with a more complete and better example. It's a mystery to me what's so mysterious for you about this.

Comment: Any way Thanks guys have figured it out. Thanks for your help. After the entire testing I shall post the solution. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_fill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) maybe?

```
<?php
$n = 10;
$arr = array_fill(0,$n,0);
foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
  $arr[$k] = $k;
}
print_r($arr);
```

Or, as suggested by @[deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze), use [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

```
<?php
$n = 10;
$arr = array();
foreach(range(0,$n-1) as $v) {
  $arr[$v] = $v;
}
print_r($arr);
```

Or when the value is the same as the key, you can use just this:

```
<?php
$n = 10;
$arr = range(0,$n-1);
// no foreach needed
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: If you're using `range`... why are you looping again to replicate the same range...?

Comment: The Value for $n is not in my control. The no. of iterations that the loop will be implemented is not known to me.

Comment: yes, you could always set the `$n` with any value from client/user, for example from `$_POST` or `$_GET` or `readline()`

Comment: if the `$n` size is from textbox, you could just create a textbox `<input name='no' />` then retrieve it on the `PHP` file like this: `$n = $_GET['no'];`

Answer (score 0):

foreach() works for object and array not for a single value.

What you can do create an array or object from users input.

like:

```
$userInput = 10;
$forEachArray = array_fill(0, $userInput, 0);

$arrayToDisplay = array();
foreach($forEachArray as $key){
   $arrayToDisplay[$key] = $key;
}
print_r($arrayToDisplay);
```

Comment: Of course you could just do `array_combine($forEachArray, $forEachArray)` instead of `foreach`. Or just do `range(0, $userInput)` to begin with.